# Strange Unexpected token ILLEGAL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encoding, error-handling

I have a syntax error which I cannot solve.
Based on W3 jQuery schools, this should be okay.
Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(“a”).click(function(){
            **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**
                $(#content).toggle(400);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: "Based on W3 JQuery schools" — Based on what?!

Comment: Please see my comment to CWolves below. It looked the same, but was not. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @Hans I've always wondered, how "smart quotes" end up to people's code, now I know, thanks for that : ).

Answer (score 7):

Strings need to be surrounded with `U+0022` (double quote - `"`) characters or `U+0027` (apostrophe - `'`) characters.

Your first selector, `a` is surrounded with a pair of `U+201C`/`U+201D` (left double quotation mark/right double quotation mark - `“`/`”`) characters.

Your second selector (`#content`) has no quotes around it at all.

Comment: Quentin, that is it! See also my reply to CWolves. I prepared the code in WORD and then copied it into WordPress. The " " look the same, but apparently are different. GREAT THANKS.

Comment: Word is designed for entering human languages, and does automatic conversion of certain characters to ones which are (usually) better choices (from a typographic perspective). It's a terrible tool for typing code. I recommend Sublime Text (or Komodo Edit if you want a free solution).

Answer (score 3):

You selector needs to be a string

```
$(#content).toggle(400);
```

Should be

```
$("#content").toggle(400);
```

Take a look here for more reading jQuery Selectors. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: And the quotes around `"a"` need to be normal quote characters, not matched ascii quotes

Comment: CWolves: that was it! I prepared the code in WORD and then copied it into WordPress. The " " look the same, but apparently are different. GREAT THANKS, I was already getting crazy.