# How to retain old values for HTML controls when jQuery UI dialog box is closed ("cancelled")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a JQuery UI modal dialog box in the form of an HTML (well ...) `form` with `select` and `input` (checkbox) controls. The dialog box and the controls work as one would expect, except that the controls retain their new states (e.g. checkbox selected) even if I close the dialog boxes window (or press a button "Cancel").

Is there any mechanism whereby I can make a jQuery UI dialog box retain the old control states when a certain exit button (e.g. "Cancel") is pressed, or do I have do roll my own state management in JavaScript (I hope not).

Here's an example of what currently happens and should not:

1. Enter dialog box.
2. Checkbox is off.
3. Change checkbox from off to on.
4. Close dialog box window.
5. Open it again.
6. Checkbox is on (I want it to be off, because the dialog box was previously "cancelled").

**UPDATE** Here is a relevant portion of my HTML, including a call to `clone()`.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var dialog = $("form.dialog").clone().dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).submit();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    $(“#dialog-button”).on("click", function() {
        dialog.dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

```
<form hidden method="post" action="" class="dialog" class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header" title=“Test”>

        <select name="name">

            </option>
                <option value="value">
                Test
                </option>
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery

Comment: @ScottHarris similar but not equivalent. My controls were not previously "empty" but in a distinct state.

Comment: That HTML is pretty invalid and incomplete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the form using the `reset()` method of native `<form>` element as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  var dialog = $("form.dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Ok",
      click: function() {
        $(this).submit();
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "Cancel",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close").get(0).reset(); //reset the form
      }
    }],
    close: function() {
      this.reset(); //reset the form
    }
  });

  $("#dialog-button").on("click", function() {
    $("form.dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" class="dialog" class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header" title="Test">
  <select name="name">
    <option value="value">Test</option>
    <option value="value">Option</option>
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" />
</form>
<button id="dialog-button">Open</button>
```

---

The `reset()` method belongs to `DOM` Element. Inside the callback functions `this`  refer to the native `DOM` element.

`dialog()` is a jQuery function. So for closing the dialog we create a jquery object by wrapping `this` inside `$()` and call `$(this).dialog("close");`.

Now, the jquery object `$(this)` doesn't have the `reset()` method, So we extract the `DOM` element from it using jQuery `get()` method and call it's `reset()` like

```
 $(this).dialog("close").get(0).reset();
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$(this).dialog("close"); 
this.reset();
```

(*In short I did that to reduce the number of lines by chaining*)

Inside the `close` callback, Since we don't have to close the dialogue manually by calling jquery method, We don't need a jquery object - we simply call `this.reset()` for resetting.

Reference:

- [`HTMLFormElement.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset)
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get)

Side note: The quotes (`“`) you're using is invalid in javascript.

Comment: +1 Excellent and definitely the right way to go. Can you please explain a bit more about `$(this).dialog("close").get(0).reset()` vs. `this.reset()` (i.e. `$(this)` vs. `this` as applied here). What's wrong about the quotes? So two more sentences please.

Comment: @Drux Hi, I added why I used `$(this)` and `this` in two places... The quotes will throw error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`... it's not a legal js token... see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663643/2333214) for more info.

Comment: Thx. Those illegal quotes must be awkward copy-paste effects. I do not receive such ERRORs in my code. Will try to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

What i might do in this case is to clone the `form` before creating the dialog. Then, create the dialog with the cloned element. This way, the controls should be unconnected.

```
$('form.myForm').clone().dialog();
```

Note that they should not have IDs, as that would end up with duplicated IDs in a document.

Comment: +1 Will try ... hint re ids esp. helpful. I guess you don't have to do anything special about getting rid of the the cloned dialog box later on, right?

Comment: Well, if you don't want a bunch of unused dialogs clogging up the DOM, you can remove them when they're closed.

Comment: I've now tried it with clone(), but that does not seem to make a difference. I've also included the relevant portion of HTML in the updated question. Can you spot some other problems there?